# ListBox will only scroll up when put inside ExpanderView

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm relatively new to XAML and Windows Phone development.

I have a ListBox that display a text block. Everything works fine when I just have the ListBox inside a grid, including the scrolling. I wanted the user to be able to collapse the ListBox if they wanted more space on the page to look at other elements, so I surrounded the ListBox with an ExpanderView. Once I did that though, the ListBox won't scroll down anymore. If I try to scroll down, it acts as if I am trying to scroll up and "squishes" the text vertically. If I try to scroll up, it also "squishes" the text vertically, but that is the expected behavior for scrolling up.

Here is the relevant part of my XAML code:

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView Header="Chatlog" x:Name="chatlogExpander" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2">
    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding chatlog}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ChatBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <Run Text="{Binding player}" Foreground="{Binding color}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/><Run Text="{Binding text}" Foreground="{Binding color}" FontSize="24"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
</toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

I appreciate any help you guys can give me!

Answer (score 0):

I tried an example with your code and after specifying a Height for the ListBox, it started to scroll fine.